# How to add column to a generate_series query

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, greenplum, generate-series

When looking a date ranges, is there anyway to have `generate_series` return the starting and ending dates as well?

```
select 
    '2014-06-05 00:00:00'::timestamp + ('1 month'::INTERVAL * s.a) AS date 
from 
    generate_series(1, cast(extract(month from age('2014-09-05'::date, '2014-06-05'::date)) AS integer), 1) as s(a);
```

Gives this output

```
date
2014-07-05 00:00:00
2014-08-05 00:00:00
2014-09-05 00:00:00
```

This is fine, however I would like to have

```
start_date     end_date       date
2014-06-05    2014-09-05    2014-07-05 00:00:00
2014-06-05    2014-09-05    2014-08-05 00:00:00
2014-06-05    2014-09-05    2014-09-05 00:00:00
```

The reason being is that I am extracting multiple start/end pairs from another table but cannot figure out a way of joining them together.  I am also using PostgeSQL version 8.2.15 (hence the more complicated `generate_series` function).

To expand this to my primary problem, I have a table that contains these start and end time pairs.

```
    start_date         end_date
2014-08-25 00:00:00 2014-09-25 00:00:00
2014-05-16 00:00:00 2014-08-16 00:00:00
2014-09-09 00:00:00 2014-12-09 00:00:00
2014-06-05 00:00:00 2014-07-05 00:00:00
2014-05-19 00:00:00 2014-08-19 00:00:00
2014-05-15 00:00:00 2014-07-15 00:00:00
2014-09-04 00:00:00 2014-11-04 00:00:00
```

How can I iterate through this table and join it with the expanded date ranges?

Comment: Since the two columns you want to add are part of the query, I'm assuming your actual problem is that you are generating this query somewhere, and want to only input those values once? Although, you already mention the start date twice in the query...

Comment: @IMSoP Yes, I am getting the start (2014-06-05) and end (2014-09-05) values from another table.  I thought providing a simplified example would be the most helpful as I cannot even accomplish that task.

Comment: I think in this case, you've simplified too far: the exact scenario you give is trivial: `Select '2014-09-05'::date as start_date,
    '2014-06-05'::date as end_date,
    '2014-06-05 00:00:00'::timestamp + ('1 month'::INTERVAL * s.a) AS date ...` You'll need to show us how you're combining this with the other table, or at least give us more information on the input data.

Comment: You are mixing "date" and "timestamp" freely. Please be precise. Don't call timestamps "date" and vice versa. Can we assume you are interested in *dates*?

Comment: Apologies, yes I am interested only in dates.

Comment: When you say "PostgreSQL 8.2" you actually mean "Greenplum Database" or "Amazon Redshift", don't you? (Please tell me you do, because  PostgreSQL 8.2 is ridiculously outdated).

Comment: @CraigRinger, yes I meant greenplum but I didn't realize that made it a major difference.  When I ran `select version();` it returned the initial PostgreSQL 8.2.15 and I believed that was the primary component.  I am clearly not an expert when it comes to SQL dialects but I am trying to learn.  Apologies for any misunderstandings.

Comment: @charles `SELECT version()` reports something like `PostgreSQL 8.2.15 (Greenplum Database 4.3.0.0 build 3) `. And yeah, it's that important, it's a major fork that's mostly based on an old version of PostgreSQL. If you say "PostgreSQL 8.2" people will just tell you to upgrade, plus lots of solutions for real PostgreSQL (even 8.2 compatible) won't work on Greenplum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider upgrading to a [current version](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Postgres 8.2 is long dead and forgotten.

For Postgres 8.2 (or later, but there are more elegant solutions in modern Postgres).

Assuming it's *all* about **dates**, not timestamps.

Providing `start_date` and `end_date` *once*:

```
SELECT start_date, end_date
     , (start_date + interval '1 month'
                   * generate_series(1, months))::date AS the_date
FROM  (  
   SELECT extract(month from age(end_date, start_date))::int AS months
        , start_date, end_date
   FROM (SELECT '2014-06-05'::date AS start_date
              , '2014-09-05'::date AS end_date
        ) data
   ) sub;
```

Using column name `the_date` instead of `date` which shouldn't be used as identifier.

Drawing values from table `t` instead:

```
SELECT start_date, end_date
     ,(start_date + interval '1 month'
                  * generate_series(1, months))::date AS the_date
FROM  (SELECT *, extract(month FROM age(end_date, start_date))::int AS months
       FROM   t) sub;
```

Without subquery

```
SELECT t_id, start_date, end_date
     ,(start_date + interval '1 month'
                  * generate_series(1, extract(month from age(end_date
                                                            , start_date))::int)
                  )::date AS the_date
FROM   t;
```

[**SQL Fiddle** for Postgres 8.3.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/e29d1/5)

Comment: This is very close, however, I have just edited my initial question.  I am drawing dates from another table.  How can I 'expand' that table to include the date ranges?  Also, I would gladly update the version if I could but my company has this version at present and is slow to upgrade.

Comment: @charles: Added some more. Assuming it's all about dates, not timestamps.

Comment: Sorry for delayed accept.  I had to go out of town this past weekend and didn't have very much time to check in on this question.  Thank you very much, this code works perfectly.